# Why are HTTP images not appearing in HTTPS application?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, image, https, arcgis

I have secured (HTTPS) ASP.Net MVC 4 application that uses unsecured (HTTP) ArcGIS map services. These services are called using JavaScript to get relevant map images.

If I use HTTP for my app, everything works as expected. But if I use HTTPS, IE10 and Chrome do not display the requested map images (IE prompts to display unsecured content) but Safari shows the image, no questions asked.

As an example, say my application is **https**://app.mydomain.com and my map services are at **http**://gis.mydomain.com

I run fiddler and see the response as something like (removed some parameters to simplify): **http**://gis.mydomain.com/arcgis/rest/services/Energy/BaseService/MapServer/export?....&f=image
but the image is not shown. If I enter this URL directly into my address bar, the expected image is shown.

There are no errors reported anywhere, including IIS 7.5 logs. I realize that mixed content is not ideal but I have no option at the moment. I have found lots of references to SilverLight with regard to this type of problem, but I am only using javascript and ASP.Net. I also compared the page source for both https and http - there is no difference.

Comment: Is it possible to access `http://gis.mydomain.com` by `https://gis.mydomain.com`?

Comment: No, not at this stage but I can see that is what I need to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While browsing a secure site, the browser will not load "nonsecure items" unless you (the visitor) authorize it.

The only way to solve this from server-side is by making the "nonsecure" content secure, by placing it under a https domain aswell.

Update:

By the way, if you don't specify the protocol in the content URLs, for exemple `//gis.mydomain.com` without specifying if it is `http://` or `https://`, the browser will automatically assume the same protocol that was used to access the website to load this content too.

So if you access with `http://` it will load the dependencies using `http://` as well, and if you use `https://` it will do the same.

Comment: OK, so it is purely browser/client behavior? I was lead to believe otherwise because IE prompted me to allow mixed content, but still didn't display it. Chrome didn't display the unsecure content either, but Safari loaded it, no questions asked.

Comment: Most likely. And most browsers can be configured to always display mixed content without asking, thats probably whats going on with your Safari (that by the way uses the same engine as Chrome). You can make Firefox display it by clicking a shield icon that is displayed next to the address bar while browsing a page with mixed content.

Comment: ...and in Chrome by starting it with the `--allow-running-insecure-content` command-line flag.

Comment: @Havenard  Hi,Suppose loading HTTP images under a Google browser HTTPS site doesn't work, is that the same reason?

Answer (score 1):

Another way of getting around this is to proxy the insecure content via your (https) host. ESRI have some slightly out-of-date docco on this process (including an example ASP.Net proxy page) [here](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/help/jshelp_start.htm#jshelp/ags_proxy.htm), but most/all of it should still hold in the latest versions of the API. From memory, they recently (3.5?) made the proxy configurable on a per-service basis, which is very handy.

You can ignore the token-based authentication stuff in your case, all you're really looking for is to have the insecure content come through a secure host.

Comment: I was pleased to see your response but it doesn't seem to work as the ArcGIS server still responds with an http address for the exported image, and IE10 recognizes it as unsecure content. Just to make sure we are "on the same page", I created a proxy.ashx in my app as outlined by ESRI and all map service requests are prefixed with https://mysite/proxy.ashx - the proxy just forwards the unsecure request to ArcGIS.

Comment: Clarification - did you configure your instance to use the proxy? Sorry for the lazy linking, here's some more [up to date documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jshelp/ags_proxy.html) - have you set `esri.config.defaults.io.proxyUrl` and/or `esri.config.defaults.io.alwaysUseProxy`?

Comment: No, not like this. I didn't get a lot of time to investigate, but thanks for the additional info. I will take another look as soon as I can. I also discovered that my arcgis CDN was hardcoded as http just to add to my confusion.

Comment: Thanks again @Juffy - I learned a lot as I was not using the proxy in the way it was intended. I was hard-wiring the urls until seeing your comment above. Everything is now displayed, Chrome still reports unsecure content. Fiddler shows that there is an http call to /arcgis/rest/info (bypassing the proxy), but overall its a good result.