# Github pages doesnt show HTTP urls

Tags: reactjs, github, pythonanywhere

I have a React website hosted on Github Pages, and a Flask Server running to put information on my ArangoDB server which is hosted on a machine that has HTTP address lets call it (http://21.23.24.25:8352)

The problem is that I try to show images which are stored on my local server for e.g.: http://21.23.24.25:8352/data/images/image.jpg

and I'm getting an error: `net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

How can I bypass this other than creating a new ArangoDB server hosted on another machine, or creating a SSL Certificate on the machine.

I also paid for the pythonanywhere subscription, I thought maybe it was required to bypass the SSL issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Unless this page is just for you (?) you cannot bypass https security restrictions. Why not host the images on the same GitHub pages repo?

Comment: There’s probably a better duplicate, but does this answer your question? [Why are HTTP images not appearing in HTTPS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671648/why-are-http-images-not-appearing-in-https-application)